# how do I directly access attributes of an atomic vector in R?

Tags: r, excel, spss

I have a data.frame that was created using read.spss() from the "foreign" package, which converts an .sav file to a data.frame. This converted data.frame contains 2 atomic vectors, each of which carry two attributes, "value.labels", and "names":

```
str(myfile)
'data.frame':   12265 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ PARM_ID : atomic  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named num  302 301 299 298 297 296 294 293 291 290 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "Xylenes, Total" "Nitrogen Kjeidahl" "pH" "Zinc, Total" ...
 $ CORE_ID : atomic  6673 11434 26919 26919 33488 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named num  248003 230321 148842 145884 144206 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "C&D Disposal Tech.,LLC" "Frank Road (AGG ROK Demo LF) " "Tunnel Hill Reclamation" "TWL - Penn Ohio" ...
```

I know I can get to the attributes using attr(), but is there a direct subsetting method, such as [], or $ to access these attributes?

Related question:
In further converting this data.frame to Excel using write.xlsx() (package xlsx), it appears that only the atomic portion of the two fields is carried over, not the attributes. Is there a way to have the attributes also written to excel?

One way I suppose would be to unwrap(?) the attributes, in R, into their own columns. Then write.xlsx would convert them correctly. Any way to do this?

thanks!!

Comment: Looks like the "names" attribute belongs to the "value.label"-object so it's an attribute within an attribute. You need either `attr` or `attributes`. You should post output from `dput( lapply( head(myfile), drop.levels) )` so we have something manageable to work with.

Comment: Thanks Bonded, sorry for the messy question (lapply( head(myfile), drop.levels) doesn't run btw). At any rate, is there a way to pull out the attributes into a new column?  thanks!

Comment: I'm sure there is but if you don't want to use attr() then you seem to be avoiding coding your own solution. I think you should look at the facilities provided through `memisc::spss.portable.file`

Comment: I'm just trying to learn more about access to atomic vectors and their attributes; not looking to avoid anything. No SPSS available, so cant create portable file. I simply had the .sav file dumped on my desk to see if I could recreate the data, which I did in R, and then found these rather awkward attributes. thanks again!

Comment: You job is to make this easy for people who want to help. You should make the effort to find a .sav file that has the labeling so we have something to work with.

Comment: Not sure what you mean Bonded, a .sav that "has the labeling". What is it that I need to provide? You're making it sound like I'm being reluctant to work, not willing to make it easy to answer, but this is just not the case. These attributes just have me stumped, that's all.